# How to update one table based on aggregate query form another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have two tables.

## Table A

- id
- A_status
- parent_id_B

## Table B

- id
- B_status

So for each id in B can have many records in A.

Now my question is, I need to set B_status to 1 when all child entries in Table A with same parent_id_B has A_status =1, else set B_status = 2

Ex:

```
Table A:
id    A_status    parent_id_B
1     1           1
2     1           1
3     1           2
4     1           3
5     1           3

Table B:
id    B_status
1     0
2     0
3     0

Expected result:
Table B:
id    B_status
1     1
2     1
3     1
```

Now consider another scenario

```
Table A:
id    A_status    parent_id_B
1     1           1
2     1           1
3     2           2
4     2           3
5     1           3

Table B:
id    B_status
1     0
2     0
3     0

Expected result:
Table B:
id    B_status
1     1
2     2
3     2
```

I need this to work only on sqlite. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this can be done like so:

```
UPDATE TableB
SET B_Status = 
(SELECT MAX(A_Status) FROM TableA WHERE TableA.Parent_ID_B = TableB.ID);
```

[SqlFiddle with your second case here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e6677/1)

In a more general case (without relying on direct mapping of A's status, you can also use a `CASE ... WHEN` in the mapping:

```
UPDATE TableB
SET B_Status = 
  CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(A_Status) 
       FROM TableA 
       WHERE TableA.Parent_ID_B = TableB.ID) = 1
  THEN 1
  ELSE 2
END;
```

**Edit** (in the case where there are more than the original number of states):

I believe you'll need to determine 2 facts about each row, e.g.

- Whether there is are any rows in table A with a status other than 1 for each B
- And there must at least be one row for the same B
- Or, whether the count of rows of A in state 1 = the count of all rows in A for the B.

Here's the first option:

```
UPDATE TableB
SET B_Status = 
  CASE WHEN 
    EXISTS
     (SELECT 1 
      FROM TableA 
      WHERE TableA.Parent_ID_B = TableB.ID 
      AND TableA.A_Status <> 1)
    OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
      FROM TableA 
      WHERE TableA.Parent_ID_B = TableB.ID)
  THEN 2
  ELSE 1
END;
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9bab3/6)

Comment: MAX(A_Status) will not work for me since, there are more states to my A_Status like 3,4 etc and I always want B_Status to be either 1 or 2. 1 if all related entries A == 1 and 2 if any one of the related entries in A is != 1 (can be 2, 3, 4 etc) [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9bab3/1)